# How to format strings and decimals while appending to list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, formatting

I am trying to format decimal (to 2 decimal points) and possibly strings **WHILE BUILDING a list** that contains dictonaries.  I am using Python 3.

This is what I came up with, but obviously it doesn't work (hence the question.)

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.datalist = []

    def push_data(self, s1, int2, flt3):
        self.datalist.append({
            "s1": '%s',
            "int2": '%i',
            "dec3": '%0.2f'
        }) % (s1, int2, flt3)

    def print_data(self):
        print(self.datalist)


f = foo()
f.push_data("HelloWorld", 1, 3.1415)
f.print_data()
```

I would like the list to contain

```
[{'s1': 'HELLOWORLD', 'dec2': 1.00, 'dec3': 3.14}]
```

Please remember, I **AM NOT** trying to format the data on ouput/print, but as the data is placed/appended to the list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: This is the error produced
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Comment: @StephenRauch Curious how this is not a "minimal, complete, and verifiable" example?  Please explain your critique and proposed improvement so that we all may benefit from "better answers".  Thanks.

Comment: When I left the comment there was no indication of what you expected the output to be.  You edited the question after the comment was left.

Comment: My apologies @StephenRauch . Blessings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to format each field individually:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.datalist = []

    def push_data(self, s1, int2, flt3):
        self.datalist.append({
            "s1": '%s' % s1,
            "int2": '%i' % int2,
            "dec3": '%0.2f' % flt3
        })

    def print_data(self):
        return self.datalist


f = foo()
f.push_data("HelloWorld", 1, 3.1415)
f.print_data()

# [{'dec3': '3.14', 'int2': '1', 's1': 'HelloWorld'}]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I knew it was a simple solution to my error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when formatting each element, and not at the end of all items, it's a small change from your code but it works:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.datalist = []
    def push_data(self, s1, int2, flt3):
        self.datalist.append({
            "s1": '%s' % s1,
            "int2": '%i' % int2,
            "dec3": '%0.2f' % flt3
        })
    def print_data(self):
        return self.datalist


f = foo()
f.push_data("HelloWorld", 1, 3.1415)
f.print_data()
```

The result is:

> [{'s1': 'HelloWorld', 'int2': '1', 'dec3': '3.14'}]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.datalist = []

    def push_data(self, s1, int2, flt3):
        self.datalist.append("{"\
            "s1: %s,"\
            "int2: %i,"\
            "dec3: %0.2f}" % (s1, int2, flt3))

    def print_data(self):
        return self.datalist


f = foo()
f.push_data("HelloWorld", 1, 3.1415)
f.print_data()
```

Produces

> ['{s1: HelloWorld,int2: 1,dec3: 3.14}']

Comment: this is not what I want, as this is simply creating a single string element in the list.  Note, that I specified a dictionary at the list entry item.  While the format appears similar it is not a dictionary, but is a simple single quoted string.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for misunderstanding, I had trouble understanding the intent of your question :)